# Effect of *p = array[i]?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, variable-assignment

I've seen an assignment similar to

```
*p = array[i];
```

in a code base and I'm wondering what effects this has on the pointer. If this has been asked before, I apologize but the search engine kept eating my special characters and may have hampered my search.

Comment: `*p = array[i]` dereferences `p` and assigns the content of whats at `array[i]` to whatever `p` points to

Comment: Thanks, I feel better knowing I wasn't misreading that fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear because there is not enough details given.
As has been said in the comments `*p = array[i]` dereferences `p` and assigns the content of what's at `array[i]` to whatever `p` points to.

Example 1

```
int i = 0, j;
int *p = &j; // p is a pointer to integer and now it points to j
int array[2] = { 4, 2 };
*p = array[i]; // this means j = array[0] so j = 4 and j is 4 now
```

Example 2

```
int i = 0, *j, k, l;
int **p = &j; // p is a pointer to pointer to integer and now it points to j
int* array[2] = { &k, &l };
*p = array[i]; // this means j = array[0] so j = &k and j points now to k
```

Comment: "Your question is unclear because there is not enough details given" Sorry, I'll give better detail in future questions.

Comment: Hit the post button to soon. Thanks for the answer. I thought it was something like that but I'm feeling a little shaky on pointers at the moment. This helps.